# How can I retrieve the perimeter and specific geometric properties using the Model Derivative API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autocad, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

I have followed the Postman tutorial [for the model derivative API, specifically for extracting metadata.](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-tutorial-postman/tree/master/ModelDerivative_05) I used a .dxf file, since I want to know if it is possible to retrieve perimeter, length/width properties based off the file.

I received a 200 response and it gave me a massive list of objects w/ their respective objectid's. Basically I got back a ton of these:

```
            {
                "objectid": 253,
                "name": "Line [108]",
                "externalId": "108",
                "properties": {
                    "3D Visualization ": {
                        "Material": "ByLayer"
                    },
                    "General": {
                        "Color": "ByLayer",
                        "Handle": "108",
                        "Layer": "color#000000ff",
                        "Linetype": "BYLAYER",
                        "Linetype scale": "1.000",
                        "Lineweight": "ByLayer",
                        "Name ": "Line",
                        "Plot style": "ByColor",
                        "Thickness": "0.000 mm",
                        "Transparency": "ByLayer"
                    },
                    "Geometry": {
                        "Angle": "192.931 deg",
                        "Length": "0.088 mm"
                    }
                }
            }
```

The .dxf file I tested was as simple as possible and it looks like this image:

[image]

How can I retrieve the perimeter of this image? Is it possible to retrieve other specific geometric properties that I specify?

How can I know what part of the .dxf file each objectid is referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Although it looks simple, the polyline (?) is probably being tessellated, resulting in a large number of small lines. Have you tried the original DWG file? Can you try that with viewer.autodesk.com?